# XPath select parent attribute and child element data

Tags: xpath

XPath newbie here.

Is there a way to select a list of `attr1` and `child3` pairs using XPath from the sample XML below?

In other words I need a list of `a11, c13`, `a21, c23`, etc.

Or I can only do `//parent` and pick required values from the array of resulting nodes?

```
<parentList>
  <parent attr1="a11" attr2="a12">
    <child1>c11</child1>
    <child2>c12</child2>
    <child3>c13</child3>
    <child4>c14</child4>
    <child5>c15</child5>
  </parent>
  <parent attr1="a21" attr2="22">
    <child1>c21</child1>
    <child2>c22</child2>
    <child3>c23</child3>
    <child4>c24</child4>
    <child5>c25</child5>
  </parent>
</parentList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This xpath 2.0 expression (and properly closing your sample html)

```
//parent/concat(@attr1,' ',child3/text())
```

should output:

```
a11 c13
a21 c23
```

Comment: And is it possible to return this as array of objects?  Something like `[{attr: 'a11', text: 'c13'}, {attr: 'a21', text: 'c23'}]`.  Also no way to achieve this using XPath 1.0 without using position?

Comment: @krl As to xpath 1.0 - I don't think so. As to the array issue, you can do something like that using the xpath 3.1 array constructor; otherwise you will probably have to use your host language. It may actually be a good idea to post the array question as a separte question and let the xpath gurus weigh in.

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 solution to select the elements of interest :

```
//parent/descendant-or-self::*[position()=1 or position()=4]
```

But, to generate a list of data you should use the following one  :

```
(//@attr1|//text()[normalize-space()])[parent::parent or parent::*[parent::parent][count(preceding-sibling::*)=2]]
```

Look for an attribute or text with : `parent` element as parent or child of `parent` as parent and two preceding siblings.

Output : `a11,c13,a21,c23`